# Jenkins/Git: Build latest from branches + manual build from any commit

Tags: git, jenkins

I am trying to set up Jenkins with a Git project so that:

1. It will build from branches matching a pattern (*origin/master*, *origin/feature/**, *origin/hotfix/**, etc.) whenever changes are pushed to the central repository
2. Developers and testers can trigger a build for any revision they want, specified as a build parameter that is a tag name, branch name or commit hash. The job has other parameters and we will occasionally want to create builds with something other than the default values.

I have got 1. working correctly by setting up a post-receive script on the Git server and adding multiple branch specifiers in Jenkins.

In order to also do 2., I added an extra build parameter `GitRef` and then added an extra branch specifier with `$GitRef`. Manually starting a build would then just keep building from the same commit/branch every time, whatever the parameter was set to. If I removed all the other branch specifiers, the manual builds would work as expected. But then the hook-triggered builds would only build from *origin/master* (the default value of `$GitRef`).

Is what I am trying to achieve even possible without creating a two jobs for every project? If so, what do I need to do to get it working?

Comment: you are interested in this topic yet?

Comment: I never did manage to get this working. We're just doing without manually triggered builds now. I had a look at the plugin code but I couldn't quite get my head around it. As far as I could tell, it didn't resolve the macros at the right point and that's why it didn't do what I wanted.

Comment: you need something like  "Gitlab Merge Request Builder Plugin" (Ref: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Gitlab+Merge+Request+Builder+Plugin)

Answer (score 2):

If you install the [Git Parameters Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Parameter+Plugin) you can allow users to start a parameterized build using a specific commit ID, branch or tag.

You can then set the default value for your parameters as `**` and by default, Jenkins will build the latest commit on branches.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `$GitRef` as another branch specifier, just use it as a String variable with no default value. Then, as the first step of your build phase in Jenkins, have a script that checks if that value is set:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ -n $GitRef ]
then
  echo "Manually specified reference found. Building $GitRef"
  git checkout $GitRef
else  
  echo "No explicit branch specified, building $GIT_BRANCH" 
fi
```

At this point, run your build as per normal (e.g. Maven). The build will run whatever branch/tag/commit you wish to compile, and if it doesn't exist Jenkins should take care of the `git checkout <bad_ref>` by failing the build.